# How to save Box file to computer as pdf?

Tags: pdf, save-as, box.com

Someone just sent me a link to their PDF hosted on Box. I can't for the life of me figure out how to save this file as a PDF. Right-clicking `save-as` comes up with an html file. Right-clicking `print` comes up with a blank document. I tried signing up for Box because I thought maybe it would give me the option then, but it doesn't appear to have changed any save options.

How can I save a Box file (that someone shared with me) to my computer as a PDF?

Comment: Did they perhaps share the file with you allowing you only to read it and not download it? I don't know if this is a feature of Box.com, but it would not surprise me. Also, what happens if you just click on the file to open it?

Comment: @music2myear When I click the link to open, the file is displayed in my web browser, and it's hosted on the Box domain. In the top left, I can click the Box logo to go back to the Box homepage, in the top right I can click "Go to your files", and at the bottom I can click to zoom in/out, previous/next page, and enter fullscreen. Those are my only options outside of the browser/right click menus which won't let me save as a pdf, or print as a pdf (because the print screen preview displays a blank page).

Comment: Then I am guessing the file was shared with you for viewing only. Like I said, I'm not familiar with whether Box has this feature or not, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Box Reference Page](https://view.box.com/reference#post-sessions) it is stated that you are able to set a BODY parameter `is_downloadable`. When this is set you can access the file via `/sessions/{id}/content`.

[image: Box Reference Page is_downloadable]